# Android app runs on Dalvik but crashes with NoClassDefFoundError on Android Runtime

Tags: java, android

My application runs just fine on Dalvik, but when I attempt to run it on ART I get a NoClassDefFoundError.  I'm using Android Studio 0.6.1

Here is the stack trace:

```
06-20 16:13:05.376  16008-16008/com.myapp.android I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on
previously-failed class java.lang.Class<net.sf.cglib.transform.AbstractProcessTask>
06-20 16:13:05.376  16008-16008/com.myapp.android D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-20 16:13:05.376  16008-16008/com.myapp.android E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapp.android, PID: 16008
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.sf.cglib.transform.AbstractProcessTask
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:305)
        at com.droidbase.Loader.getClassForFile(Loader.java:155)
        at com.droidbase.Loader.getClassesForFiles(Loader.java:145)
        at com.droidbase.Loader.getAllClasses(Loader.java:64)
        at com.droidbase.Loader.getClassesExtending(Loader.java:54)
        at com.droidbase.DroidBase.getModels(DroidBase.java:87)
        at com.droidbase.DroidBase.loadModels(DroidBase.java:97)
        at com.droidbase.DroidBase.setup(DroidBase.java:66)
        at com.droidbase.DroidBase.initialize(DroidBase.java:23)
        at com.droidbase.DroidBase.setup(DroidBase.java:27)
        at com.myapp.android.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:22)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4328)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
```

Comment: Try find the source of the problem, comment out chunks of code until the problem goes away and then narrow it down and provide the code to us that is the cause so we have a better chance of helping you.

Comment: It seems that `net.sf.cglib.transform.AbstractProcessTask` failed the ART class verifier. There should be more info about that in the logs.

Comment: There isn't anything else in the logs, so I don't think it's a problem with the class failing the verifier...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I was missing a dependency in my Gradle file.  In my case I needed to add the line `compile 'org.apache.ant:ant:1.9.4'` to my dependencies.  Why this worked on Dalvik but not ART is beyond me.